# Python: Methods inside a method in a class

Tags: python, class, methods

```
import numpy as np

class Y:
    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def f(self,x):
        return x

    def g(self,x):
        return f(x)**2
y=Y()
print y.g(3)
```

I know the above code will give error, but somehow I want to do the following, is there a modification to do?

Comment: Change "return f(x)**2" to "return self.f(x)**2"

Comment: `__init__` shouldn't return anything. If you want it to do nothing, use `pass`.

Comment: Every function returns something. If the function has a lone `return` or simply ends with no `return` statement at all, it returns `None` by default. Adding a `return None` to the end of a method that traditionally has no `return` statement doesn't bother it.

Comment: If `__init__()` doesn't do anything, just leave it out.

Comment: `g()` should be `return self.f(x)**2`.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason it doesn't work is because you have `f(x)**2` instead of `self.f(x)**2`. Make that change and it'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. It just takes a simple change. Since `f(x)` is a method, you need to call it on some object. What you want here is to call it on yourself, so very simply that line becomes:

```
return self.f(x)**2
```